# R Data Table Return Row Numbers of Matches

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the data.table package to work through a the House Prices data set from Kaggle.

When I retrieve the matches from the data table syntax, the row numbers are not returned with the data.

```
combined_df[is.na(GarageArea), garage_num_vars, with = FALSE]

   GarageYrBlt GarageCars GarageArea
1:        1923         NA         NA
```

How can I get the actual row number with that observation?  I have seen many solutions using .I and using which = TRUE but how would I add the which = TRUE argument to my current syntax?

Comment: Why not just add a row number as a column to the original data?

Comment: In other words, when convert your data to a data.table specify the `keep.rownames` parameter as in `setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding a column of row number as suggested in the comment, you can also use `which` argument in this way:

```
DT <- data.table(val = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4))
# > DT
#    val
# 1:   1
# 2:   2
# 3:   3
# 4:  NA
# 5:   4

x <- DT[is.na(val), which = TRUE]

cbind(rownum = x, DT[x])
#    rownum val
# 1:      4  NA
```